# Importing bootstrap on a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails engine, and I want to use bootstrap on it.

I included 'bootstrap' as a dependency. And I want to import in my application.scss file.

However, importing like this:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Doesn't work as normal. I suspect that it is because I'm running an engine, and my scss file is placed in a module instead of the `/stylesheets` directory. However,

```
@import '../bootstrap';
```

does not work either.

Any ideas, and in addition, is there something fundamental I should know about rails engines when it comes to referencing by directory and what not? I only ask because this is the first time I've ever worked with a rails engine

***UPDATE***

It appears that also the `jquery-rails` gem (in addition to boostrap) could not be found when I require it in my application.js file like this:

```
//= require jquery-rails
//= require bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to change:

```
s.add_dependency 'bootstrap'
```

to this:

```
s.add_dependency 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
```